# Title in CSV file when converting from XML to CSV using XML

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I am trying to convert the XML to CSV using XSLT , I am getting the record but I need title in CSV file.

Eg:

```
Name    EmailAddress
Gaurav   Gaur@yopmail.com
Satya    Satya@yopmail.com
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SearchResults>
<Columns>
    <Column Label="Name">Name</Column>
    <Column Label="Email Addresses">EmailAddress</Column>
</Columns>
<Rows>
    <Row>
        <Name>Gaurav Joshi</Name>
        <EmailAddress>ybenipohe-3888@yopmail.com</EmailAddress>

    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Name>Satya</Name>
        <EmailAddress>eqaddoxoqu-8703@yopmail.com</EmailAddress>
     </Row>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <!-- This transform is used to generate a CSV file.-->
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SearchResults/Rows/Row" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/SearchResults/Rows/Row">
    <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
    <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:text>,&quot;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
      <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/SearchResults/Columns" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have a template matching `/SearchResults/Columns`, which is actually redundant at the moment, because you don't have any templates that explicitly select these (Due to you doing `<xsl:apply-templates select="/SearchResults/Rows/Row" />`).

But you can easily adapt it to output the headings, and then you would just need an `xsl:apply-templates` to select it.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <!-- This transform is used to generate a CSV file.-->
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SearchResults/Columns" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/SearchResults/Rows/Row" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:text>,"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Columns">
    <xsl:text>"Row"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="Column">
       <xsl:text>,"</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="@Label" />
       <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this makes the (big?) assumption that the child nodes of each `Row` are in the same order as the relevant `Column` nodes. If this is not the case, you have work to do. Try replacing the template matching `Row` with this one instead

```
  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="Row" select="." />
    <xsl:for-each select="/SearchResults/Columns/Column">
      <xsl:text>,"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$Row/*[name() = current()]" />
      <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```